# java.util.Timestamp.after() wrong when comparing milliseconds?

Tags: java, oracle, time

I am pulling dates out of an Oracle database. They are set on a java.util.Date field and they are in reality java.sql.Timestamp instances (which is a subclass of Java.util.Date). If I compare two of these timestamps from two different database records by calling after() on the first date and compare it to the second, I get the wrong answer when all parts of the date are the same except for the milliseconds.

All of the following should result in "true", however the second set of numbers does not:

```
firstDate  = 1/1/2000 12:00:20:00
secondDate = 1/1/2000 12:00:10:00
result = firstDate.after(secondDate);
result is TRUE <-- EXPECTED RESULT

firstDate  = 1/1/2000 12:00:00:10
secondDate = 1/1/2000 12:00:00:00
result = firstDate.after(secondDate);
result is FALSE <-- NOT EXPECTED, result should be TRUE
```

I know nanos are stored separately from the Date instance in the Timestamp class and I am curious if this is the issue.

Comment: Print the dates using SimpleDateFormat in order to debug this.

Comment: Please post the actual code, not a pseudo-code. Secondly, there is no such thing as `java.util.Timestamp`, did you mean `java.sql.Timestamp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare them, but only by comparing millis. While it's quite ugly, it seems to work in all cases (regardless of which is `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.util.Date`).

```
if(date1.getTime() > date2.getTime()) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to the problem here is when the Timestamps are cast up to Date objects.  The *after* method of Date is being used instead of the *after* method in Timestamp.  When not cast to Date, the *after* method of Timestamp will work correctly.

I guess I need a lesson now on [covariant method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413181/how-do-covariant-parameter-types-work-in-java) as to why the *after* method in Timestamp isn't called in the following code.

```
    java.sql.Timestamp one = new java.sql.Timestamp(1266873627200L);
    java.sql.Timestamp two = new java.sql.Timestamp(1266873627000L);

    java.util.Date oneDate = (java.util.Date) one;
    java.util.Date twoDate = (java.util.Date) two;


    System.out.println("one: " + oneDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("two: " + twoDate.getTime());

    if (oneDate.after(twoDate)) {
        System.out.println(oneDate.getTime() + " after " + twoDate.getTime());
    } else {
        System.out.println(twoDate.getTime() + " after " + oneDate.getTime());
    }
```

results

```
one: 1266873627200
two: 1266873627000
1266873627000 after 1266873627200
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem you're having is that firstDate and secondDate are set to Java.util.Date objects but the JavaDoc for [java.sql.Timestamp](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) mentions that it is a composite of java.util.Date and a separate nanoseconds value.

This is why it is returning false when you are trying to compare the two. If you changed firstDate and secondDate over to actual Timestamp objects they should work.

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual code this is a speculation, but I think one of your objects is `java.util.Date` and the other is `java.sql.Timestamp` you cannot really compare them, as the `millis` field in 'Timestamp' is truncated to a second and the remainder is stored in `nanos` field.  It's really unfortunate that `Timestamp` is a subclass of `Date`.  This definitely leads to a problem that you are experiencing.

**EDIT.**

One more possibility, is that your DB driver returns its own subclass of `Timestamp`. Because the class is not final it's quite possible that their implementation screwed up Timestamp's `compare`, not that it's particularly hard to do.

Comment: They are both java.sql.Timestamp instances.