# How do covariant parameter types work in java

Tags: java, overloading

Given that Date has a method called "after(Date)" and Timestamp has a method the overrides it called "after(Timestamp)", why is the *after* method in Date called in the following code?

The question as to the unexpected results was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321359/java-util-timestamp-after-wrong-when-comparing-milliseconds/2411168#2411168).

```
    java.sql.Timestamp one = new java.sql.Timestamp(1266873627200L);
    java.sql.Timestamp two = new java.sql.Timestamp(1266873627000L);

    java.util.Date oneDate = (java.util.Date) one;
    java.util.Date twoDate = (java.util.Date) two;


    System.out.println("one: " + oneDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("two: " + twoDate.getTime());

    if (oneDate.after(twoDate)) {
        System.out.println(oneDate.getTime() + " after " + twoDate.getTime());
    } else {
        System.out.println(oneDate.getTime() + " not after " + twoDate.getTime());
    }
```

results

```
one: 1266873627200
two: 1266873627000
1266873627200 not after 1266873627000
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overloads are considered at compile-time; overrides are considered at execution time.

Timestamp *overloads* `after`, it doesn't *override* an existing method - so your `oneDate.after(twoDate)` is only considering the methods in `java.util.Date`; furthermore even if you use `one.after(twoDate)` it would *still* only use `after(Date)` because the compile-time type of `twoDate` is `Date` rather than `Timestamp`.

If you call `one.after(two)` then *that* will use `Timestamp.after(Timestamp)`.

`Date.after(Date)` only considers the milliseconds - but `Timestamp` only passes an integral number of seconds to the constructor of `Date`, so `oneDate` and `twoDate` have an equal millisecond value in `Date`, even though you passed different values to the constructors.

It's worth noting this bit in the [docs for `Timestamp`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) though:

> Due to the differences between the
>   Timestamp class and the java.util.Date
>   class mentioned above, it is
>   recommended that code not view
>   Timestamp values generically as an
>   instance of java.util.Date. The
>   inheritance relationship between
>   Timestamp and java.util.Date really
>   denotes implementation inheritance,
>   and not type inheritance.

Sounds like a pretty poor use of inheritance to me, to be honest - but then Java's got plenty of those :(

Comment: The after method in Date doesn't compare nanos.

Comment: @s_t_e_v_e: Ah - I'd misread the output a bit. `!x.after(y)` isn't the same as `y.after(x)` - which is what your output suggests.